# pushViewController freezes while getting notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My app is registered for remote notification and when I got one

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        [self openTopicWithID:[userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"]];
}
```

I'm initiating view controller and pushing it in navagation controller

```
- (void)openTopicWithID:(NSString *)ID
{
    UINavigationController *rootController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardiPhone" bundle:nil];
    UICommentList *commentList = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CommentView"];
    commentList.postID = ID;
    commentList.comesFromPush = YES;
    [rootController pushViewController:commentList animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that my app is stuck and there are no errors or crashes - it just takes 100% of CPU and memory usage raise strongly.

Comment: First, I am assuming that UICommentList is your custom view controller. Stylistically, you shouldn't use the prefix 'UI' unless the class is part of UIKit, but this won't cause an error.  Have you set a break point in your openTopicWithId and single stepped to see where the hang occurs?  Same thing in UICommentList viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc

Comment: High CPU and memory usAge indicates your program is stuck in a loop. You can use the instruments tool to profile the app and see where it is getting stuck

Comment: Tnx for the help guys, I found loop on fresh head, it doesn't caused by Navigation Controller. @Paulw11 - UIComment list is a name I don't use, just invent it while creating post, for hiding real class name - company policy ;)